# Django Cast DateTimeField to DateField splits over multiple days

Tags: django

I have a `DateTimeField` that I'm casting into a `DateField` so I can group by the date then perform some annotations. For some reason it's splitting a single timestamp for a specific date into two dates - I can't figure out why it's happening.

For example in the following I should only get one grouping as I'm specifically filtering for May 5th but it's being split into two separate dates.

```
orders = (
    Order.objects
    .filter(paid_at__date='2021-05-01')
    .annotate(paid_at_date=Cast('paid_at', DateField()))
    .order_by('paid_at_date')
    .values('paid_at_date')
    .annotate(total=Sum('total'))
)
<OrderQuerySet [{'paid_at_date': datetime.date(2021, 5, 1), 'total': Decimal('17852.30')}, {'paid_at_date': datetime.date(2021, 5, 2), 'total': Decimal('6895.30')}]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`TruncDate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate) function instead of `Cast` as it takes `tzinfo` into account.